# Databricks Drop Rollback

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, drop

Is there a way to undo drop table statemnt in Databricks. I know for delete there is time travel/restore option, but I am specifically looking for drop statemnt. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`DROP TABLE` removes data only when you have [managed table](https://docs.databricks.com/data/tables.html#managed-and-unmanaged-tables) - when you created it without explicit specification of location.  To prevent dropping of the data, create a table as unmanaged - even if you drop the table, it will remove only table definition, but not data, so you can always re-create the table using the data (it's not limited to Delta, you can use other formats as well):

- for SQL - specify path to data using `LOCATION`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE name 
USING delta
LOCATION '<path-to-data>'
```

- when using APIs (Scala/Python/R/Java) - provide the `path` option:

```py
df.write.format("delta") \
  .option("path", "path-to-data") \
  .saveAsTable("table-name")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will keep this in mind